# Global error handling of file_get_contents() PHP

Tags: php, handler, file-get-contents

I am occasionally getting errors while using file_get_contents and its used a fair bit in my script. I know I can suppress errors individually with `@file_get_contents` and that I can set global error messages with

```
//error handler function
function customError($errno)
  {
  echo 'Oh No!';
  }

//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError");
```

But how do I specifically set an error handler for all file_get_content's uses?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may set your custom error_handler before invoking file_get_contents and then use restore_error_handler() function right after file_get_contents. if there is multiple usage of file_get_contents in your code, you may wrap file_get_contents by some custom function.

Answer (score 2):

[`@`](http://php.net/@) does not really suppress the errors as you've discovered. They still show up in your custom [error handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler). And to have "suppressed" errors ignored there, you have to first probe for the current [`error_level`](http://php.net/error_level):

```
function customError($errno)
{
   if ( !error_reporting() ) return;

   echo 'Oh No!';
}

// That's what PHPs default error handler does too.
```

Just guessing. If you meant something different, please extend your question. (You cannot have an error handler invoked for *each* file_get_contents call - if there didn't occur any error.)

Answer (score 1):

or check the trace and handle error if referer function is file_get_contents

```
//error handler function
    function customError($errno)
    {
        $a = debug_backtrace();
        if($a[1]['function'] == 'file_get_contents')
        {
            echo 'Oh No!';
        }
    }

    //set error handler
    set_error_handler("customError");
```

Answer (score 0):

your error handler function would need tobe more comprehensive then that. 
you would do something like:

```
<?php 
function customError($errno,$errstr){

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            echo "<b>ERROR</b> $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        case E_USER_WARNING:
            echo "<b>WARNING</b> $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            echo "<b>NOTICE</b> $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        default:
            echo "Whoops there was an error in the code, check below for more infomation:<br/>\n";
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

set_error_handler("customError");

$filename = 'somemissingfile.txt';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
//add the trigger_error after your file_get_contents
if($file===false){trigger_error('Could not get:'.$filename.' - on line 27<br/>',E_USER_ERROR);}

?>
```